# how to access variables

Tags: java

I need to access the field name of the object that is calling. Like if obj.a() calls, it should log a

Comment: what did you try by now?

Comment: Your code is confusing. You are assigning the value to the result of calling `whatsMyName` (not the function reference) and you don't have function by that name. You do have a function `getCaller()`, but it's never used.

Comment: what you're asking is impossible. if you explained why you want to do this perhaps we could give you advice about better options.

Comment: @iwrestledabearonce it's still JS ... be careful with "impossible". But I agree that this makes little sense in a real world code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For sure this is possible, but it does make little sense though:

```
 function whatsMyName() {
   return function iKnowIt() {
     for(const [key, value] of Object.entries(this))
        if(value === iKnowIt)
           console.log(key);
   };
 }
```